# Parsing JSON in Android

Tags: android

I am about to work with **JSON** for the first time. Previously I worked on parsing *XML* in *Android*. How is it different with *JSON*? Suggest me some good tutorials for the same.

Stone

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/: This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually mean JSON right? If you're wondering about the JSON structure http://www.json.org/ is a great place to start.

I have never used JSON with android, but Googling give me this looks-promising tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [JSON](http://json.org/)? You can parse JSON very easily on Android. You can either use the built-in [`org.json`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) parser or use a third-party library, such as [`google-gson`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), or any other Java JSON library.

Comment: Sorry I spelled it incorrect. I have rectified it now. Let me see the links you have suggested.

Comment: It's pronounced "jason", which is probably why you spelled it like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
full code which run succesfully..........


package com.example.jsonparsingapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";
    JSONObject json;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new RetreiveFeedTask().execute("hbhbh");

    }


    class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        private Exception exception;
        RetreiveFeedTask()
        {

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute( ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {

            try{
                  System.out.println("in doinbackground");
                  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
                    try {
                      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                      if (statusCode == 200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                          builder.append(line);
                        }
                      } 
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                     json=new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                     System.out.println("string issssss"+builder.toString());
                     System.out.println("in doinbackground end");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                    return "hi";



        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            // TODO: check this.exception 
            // TODO: do something with the feed
            System.out.println("postexecute");
            doWork();
        }
     }



    public void doWork()
    {


        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        //System.out.println("json is"+json);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem



    }







}
```