# Get Json Information? (Noob)

Tags: android, json

I'm new to both using json and developing for android, however I'm looking to learn how to retrieve information using a json api key.

Let's say this website has all the information I need. How can I access and store that information?

```
https://website.com/api/user/key/a015b92aec875bd24e8fdc73477bfdcr
```

For example it would have something like this,

```
{"balance":"123","due":"3426"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access it, you need to open HTTPS connection to the server that has that API key, which is that https address you just provided. The server will return the JSON objects for you, to parse the string data, you can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). GSON will translate all the JSON objects into Java objects, and it will help you populate your pre-built Java data structures with those data

Answer (score 1):

You can get the web content using the Android [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) (or follow something like the guide on [this page](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a20/Android-A-Quick-and-Dirty-Http-Client.html)).

For storage, you need to parse the JSON - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437328/parsing-json-in-android).

For storage, either store the raw JSON in a file or create an SQLite database and store it according to your specifications.